# Is there a way to get if the string has a substring without maintaining the uppercase/lowercase in C#?

Tags: c#, string, windows

For example, I have a string "ZONE123". Is there a way to get 'true' value when comparing it to substring "zone" - some kind of '.Contains("zone")'?

Comment: `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `IndexOf` function:

```
   string s = "ZONE123";
   s.IndexOf("ZONE", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0
```